# Как выбрать базу данных?

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, realm-database

Мне нужно прикрепить базу данных в приложение, но я  не знаю, какую выбрать.

Есть старая добрая `SQLite` и новая современная `Realm` (я так понял? это самые крутые)

Они полностью отличаются по строению и по подходу работы.

Мне вообще нужно будет сохранять данные с сервера и потом показывать их в `GridView`.

Каждая ячейка `GridView` - это отдельный объект, который содержит картинку, несколько текстовых полей и цвет поля `background` - эти свойства я буду получать с сервера и хранить в базе.

Меня привлекает, как я понял по описанию, то, что с `Realm` работать намного проще и приятнее, но я не знаю так ли это на самом деле.

И, плюс, мне нужно будет пользоваться несколькими типами фильтров.

То есть одно из требований, чтобы фильтрация выполнялась быстро.

Как выбрать и с чего начать?

Comment: Каждый будет нахваливать то, что он выбрал для себя. Как вы думаете стали бы продуктом пользоваться милионы людей если бы он был медленным? Поэтому считаю что в данном случае выбор вам надо делать самому, а не спрашивать совета. Возьмите да попробуйте и тот и другугой продукт в каком нито тестовом приложении, это поможет сделать выбор, который больше всего вам подходит.

Comment: мне понравилась iBoxDB http://www.iboxdb.com/ - при правильной организации и индексировании дает примерно 20-30тыс записей в секунду на запрос по одной большой таблице со сложными фильтрами. Но у меня была задача беспонтовая и мне понравилось что под Unity сразу стала и заработала, с C# отлично соглауется, и пр. Не знаю какого объема у вас данные и какие требования по скорости.

Comment: @temq Есть качественные различия, поэтому выбор не так прост (смотрите мой ответ) и банальным "нахваливать то .." здесь не обойдешься. Исходить нужно из задач в первую очередь.

Answer (score 4):

Плюсы SQLite:

- Самая быстрая по скорости
- Ничего не надо подключать

Минусы SQLite:

- Неудобный, приходится писать много кода.

Плюсы Realm:

- По скорости немного уступает SQLite, по сравнению с другими ORM.
- Очень удобно работать с данными.
- Есть облачный сервис, напоминающий Firebase realtime database.

Минусы Realm:

- Так как библиотека написана на C++, она тянет за собой нативные либы, которые увеличивают вес приложения.
- По сравнению с SQLite она медленнее.
- Есть свои подводные камни.

Вывод: все зависит от того, какой проект вы пишите, если маленький то SQLite, если большой то лучше Realm. Я также вам советую посмотреть в сторону [ObjectBox](http://greenrobot.org/objectbox/). Данная библиотека лишена всех минусов. Но на данный момент она в Beta

Comment: Кстати вот да, Greenrobot очень интересоне решение делает, надеюсь у них получится, но различия между предложенными базами не только количественные, но и качественные.

Comment: Я еще могу предложить вариант с Requery. Библиотека совместима с Rx  и android data binding. поддерживает связи many to many

Comment: Мы на своих проектах используем ActiveAndroid. Очень удобная и быстрая библиотека для работы с SQLite DB. Рекомендую.

Answer (score 4):

Разница между Realm и SQLite на самом деле огромна.

Первая no-sql база данных (как например и модный сейчас Firebase) и она работает по качественно другим принципам постороения запросов, формирования структур данных, принципов связывания данных и проч. Запросы осуществляются с помощью методов класса, что сильно ограничивает их гибкость, так же здесь нет такой привычной в SQL-базах вещи, как автоинкрементируемый ID (здесь вообще концепция ID диаметрально противоположна). Взамен она предоставляет удобный доступ к данным в виде объектов и "человеческий" интерфейс взаимодействия. При запросах вы получаете готовые данные, максимально адаптированные к Java-окружению. как по сущности, так и по взаимодействию ( объекты и методы геттеры\сеттеры)

SQLite - класическая sql-база со структурой таблиц с колонками и строками, для извлечения данных используется специальный полноценный язык запросов SQL, который позволяет писать очень сложные выборки, учитывающие связи внутри базы и возможности тут, без преувеличения, безграничны, так же за этот вариант скоость работы, но работать с SQL-базами весьма хлопотно, особенно если вы не специализируетесь на них. Составить сложный запрос и даже правильно разработать структуру БД и ее связи - задачи, достойные отдельного обучения. Плюс к тому, получив выборку предстоит еще один этап связывания данных курсора с выборокой с Java-окружением, а они как бы из разных миров (табличная структура и ООП)

Что выбрать - решать вам, исходя из поставленных в проекте задач.

Мое мнение, если проект позволяет использовать Realm, я бы использовал его, однако есть множество задач, где именно SQL-база с табличной структурой в разы уместнее, то есть все зависит от структуры данных. Так же не последнее значение должна иметь сложность возможных запросов. Realm не в состоянии сделать выборку, например, по полям модели, в которой одно из полей - ссылка на другую модель, откуда нужно взять только одно из значений.

Реальный пример: таблица платежей, в которой одно из полей - ссылка на одно из полей  таблицы валют, которая содержит полное название валюты, ее кодовое международное обозначение и символ валюты (как $) и нам нужно в итоговую выборку получить только этот знак доллара.
SQL справится с этим легко одним запросом, а для Realm это непосильная (точнее многоходовая) задача.

Конкретно для описанной вами в вопросе задачи Realm предпочтительное решение.

Answer (score 2):

Realm крут если он используется для подходящих данных. Если ваши данные - некие наборы возвращаемые API, т.е. вам не нужно делать реально сложные запросы к БД на клиенте - то используйте Realm. Он особенно хорош в связке с RxJava+Retrolambda. Например вот так можно получить `Observable`, который будет высылать всю выборку при изменении к-л её элемента (`RealmResults` - это реалмовая реализация интерфейса `List` с парой особенностей).

```
public Observable<RealmResults<VkPost>> getFeedVkPostsSortedAsync(String field, Sort order) {
    return mRealm.where(VkPost.class)
            .equalTo(VkPost.FIELD_IS_IN_FEED, true)
            .equalTo(VkPost.FIELD_IS_IN_FAVORITES, true)
            .findAllSortedAsync(field, order)
            .asObservable()
            .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
            .filter(RealmResults::isValid);
}
```

Данный `Observable`, запущенный из основного потока выполнит запрос в БД асинхронно, отсеет объекты не удовлетворяющие двум условиям значений полей объектов (VkPost.FIELD_IS_IN_FEED, VkPost.FIELD_IS_IN_FAVORITES) и проверит что объекты возвращаемые полностью готовы для использования. При этом полученные таким образом объекты позволяют менять их значения так, что они сразу запишутся в БД.

С Realm главное правильно понять как оно с разными потоками работает и правильно это использовать. Если использовать её правильно, то это очень мощный и удобный инструмент. Но он да, сильно отличается от SQLite и по началу будет непривычно, а потом захочется использовать его везде, в т.ч. там где оно не вписывается, т.к. это NoSQL со всеми его особенностями и органичениями.

---

По поводу скорости не скажу, но думаю, возможность легкой организации работы в разных потоках как минимум облегчит возможность не делать вообще работы с БД в UI потоке.

Comment: скорость у нее такова, что это не является определяющим фактором. Это никак не SugarORM.