# Как создать БД в Android Studio и импортировать из нее данные?

Tags: java, android, база-данных, android-studio

Как создать БД, именно для Android Studio и какую выбрать? Также, после создания БД, планирую создать много активити с упражнениями, программами тренировок и процессом выполнения программы тренировок, расписанную на несколько дней, все данные хочу брать из бд. Как это все реализовать?

Comment: android studio это среда разработки. она позволяет тебе комфортно писать код, компилировать его и собирать apk. А БД это речь о самом андроиде. Если тебе нужна локальная БД, котороя будет лежать непосредственно на телефоне, то изучай SQLite

Comment: [Как добавить готовую базу SQLite в Android-приложение](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/readydb.php)

Comment: БД будет у меня храниться на компьютере, как тогда сделать бд?

Comment: @TimurVI То есть, создаю бд в SQLite Database Browser, и импортирую ее в Android Studio?

Comment: Пройдитесь пжл по [этому](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/) списку.У вас наверняка должна выстроиться некоторая картина с БД на андроиде.

Comment: @TimurVI Спасибо за советы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для Android базой данных "по умолчанию" является БД SQLite, для работы с которой есть все необходимые классы, интерфейсы и инструменты прямо в API Android. Для начала работы нужно только создать базу.

Вы можете создать БД на компьютере, организовав ее структуру и заполнив  необходимыми данными, затем [подключить уже готовую БД в ваш проект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523666/177345) и работать с ней через классы, которые Android предоставляет для работы с БД: `SQLiteOpenHeleper`, `SQLiteDatabase`, `Cursor` и тд. - открывать\закрывать подключение, добавлять, изменять, удалять данные в ней и делать запросы.

Так же вы можете создать всю структуру БД и наполнить ее данными [прямо в коде](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html?hl=ru) своего проекта:

1. В методе `onCreate()` класса `SQLiteOpenHelper` [создать структуру](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html?hl=ru#DbHelper).
2. Методом `insert()` класса `QLiteDatabase` [заполнить ее данными](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html?hl=ru#WriteDbRow).
3. Затем [работать с полученной](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html?hl=ru#ReadDbRow) в итоге базой данных (этот пункт справедлив и для первого варианта с копированием готовой базы)

Первый вариант значительно проще на этапе подготовки, второй не намного компактнее в плане размера итогового APK.

Однако разнообразие БД не ограничено одной SQLite и через внешние библиотеки можно подключить множество других баз данных. Хотелось бы выделить no-sql [ORM Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/), но существует и множество других как ORM, так и SQL-баз, которые можно подключить в свой проект. Выбор может [быть очень трудным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/625743/177345), особенно при недостатке знаний по этой теме

Comment: Спасибо огромное, за исчерпывающий ответ!