# Использование ORM, Android

Tags: android, orm

Здравствуйте, подскажите как правильно создать ORM бд? По нпжптию кнопки будет открываться камера, после сделанного фото, мы хотим положить его в бд, нужно использовать ORM, почему не подходит SQLite? Спасибо

Comment: ORM это обертка над управлением базой (SQLite), когда мы работает с ORM то данные пишутся и извлекаются из базы (SQLite). Не всегда это SQLite, но как правило.

Comment: Вы хотите знать, в чем разница между ORM и SQLite? тогда смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/625760/177345) (и другие ответы вопроса, но они не раскрывают именно различия полностью на мой взгляд). Если у вас другая проблема, раскройте ее смысл подробнее и не пишите о двух проблемах в одном вопросе -
 вам нужно создать ORM - какую-то из десятка уже имеющихся (подключить в проект) или написать свою собственную или все же о различиях с реляционными базами вам не понятно. В вопросе должна быть **одна конкретная** проблема  с подробным описанием

Comment: Проблема такая, у меня есть регистрация на SQLite, а изображения нужно хранить в orm, как это сделать, где этот переход?