# ORM и SQLite, можно ли одновременно использовать в Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, orm

Здравствуйте, подскажите как реализовать сохранение фото с камеры в ORM? Для создания регистрации в приложении нужно SQlite или её можно сделать через ORM?Можно ли использовать одновременно?

Comment: ORM - технология маппинга. Что значит "сохранение фото с камеры в ORM"?

Comment: регистрация в каком приложении? что SQLite, что любая ORM - базы данных - в них можно хранить **любую** информацию, в том числе логин\пароль. Фото нужно хранить на SD-карте, в БД - ссылку на фото, а не сам файл. И SQLite и ORM - базы данных, использовать их обе одновременно - масло маслянное, нужно выбрать что то одно и каждая имеет [свои преимущества и недостатки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/625760/177345).

Comment: @pavlofff ORM это не база данных, а обёртка над ней. И как раз одновременно с SQLite чаще всего и используется (в Android).

Comment: @eugeneek Под андроид есть и "чистые" noSQL  базы данных, как Realm, Objectbox, их тоже принято считать ORM (хотя по факту они ими конечно не являются), так как они поставляют данные в виде объектов и никакой SQLite они не используют. В любом случае я от вас в первый раз слышу, чтобы вместе с каким-нибудь greenDAO использовали и прямые обращения к SQLite - это несколько нелепо. Если же вы хотели сказать, что в основе той же greenDAO лежит SQLite, то я знаю конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/), точнее в сторону ее Android инкарнации. Создает маппинг Java объектов над SQLite

> подскажите как реализовать сохранение фото с камеры в ORM?

Фото можно сохранить в поле типа `BLOB`, на стороне ORM это будет `byte[]` массив:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY)
byte[] imageBytes;
```