# Как создавать одинаковые модели с разными названиями Realm

Tags: android, база-данных, realm

Собственно в Realm название класса модели совпадает с названием таблицы.
А как создать много таблиц с разными названиями но по 1 модели?
То есть допустим есть список брендов обуви, это 1 таблица
у каждого бренда есть коллекция (этих таблиц столько же сколько и брендов, хотя тожет быть даже больше, но не отвлекаемся)
у каждой модели из коллекции обуви есть: id, color, price... (которые не зависят от колекции или бренда обувь)
допустим нужно получить JSON распарсить и сохранить в таблицы.

1. Список брендов

2. collection_dolce

3. collection_eccet

............................

N. collection_xxx

Как создать эти таблицы с РАЗНЫМИ названиями по ОДНОЙ модели? В Списке брендов можно добавить колонку с названиями таблиц колекций

Comment: Только вот вчера задавался таким же вопросом :) PS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542762/multiple-realm-tables-of-same-class

Comment: А Вы поняли как это сделать порвым способом? Я что то не до конца.

Comment: У объекта создается дополнительное поле. В это поле записывается название "таблицы". Далее, при выборке просто указывается нужная "таблица".

Comment: вообще noSQL БД, как Realm для такого типа хранения не самый удачный выбор. Здесь наиболее уместна классическая реляционная БД, как SQLite и таблицы должны быть: brands - названия брендов, collections - названия коллекций с связкой к брендам и моделям, models - данные конкретных моделей с связкой к брендам и коллекциям.

Comment: А можете объяснить почему Вы так считаете? Я просто буквально второй раз realm использую, может быть действительно не прав.

Comment: Потому что noSQL плохо работает со структурами на основе связей, это не их область применения и приходится что то костылить, чтобы решить задачу, как вы сами видите. Ваши же данные 
наиболее удобно хранить и обрабатывать именно в реляционной структуре таблиц, а не на основе объектов-моделей. Вы можете использовать библиотеку google [Room Persistence Lybrary](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html) для более удобной работы с реляционной БД. Смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/625760/177345) о различиях между типами БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как создать эти таблицы с РАЗНЫМИ названиями по ОДНОЙ модели?

Насколько я знаю, из коробки такое невозможно, но есть несколько [решений](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542762/multiple-realm-tables-of-same-class), например:

Создаем в классе поле:

```
@PrimaryKey
String mTableName;
```

Далее, для группировки объектов используем это поле.

Получение объектов из конкретной группы:

```
RealmResults<MyObject> results = realm.where(MyObject.class)
                                  .equalTo("mTableName", "tableA")
                                  .findAll();
```

PS: Решение не очень хорошее, но все же.

PPS: В исходную задача не особо вчитывался, но, вроде, хорошим решением будет создать несколько таблиц со связью One-to-many.